# When is considered the birth of nonlinear optics?

Tags: physics, experimental-physics, optics

When in our recorded history did first nonlinear optics appear?

I am more interested in the first recorded use of nonlinear crystals.

Answer (score 2):

[University of Michigan Physics Department -Nonlinear Optics 50th Anniversary Symposium](http://leccap.engin.umich.edu/leccap/site/qosbcytrdws33ghva0n) was held on Octber 26, 2011.  [Peter Franken had focused a ruby laser on a quartz crystal in 1961](http://course.ee.ust.hk/elec509/readings/nonlinear%20optics.pdf).

This was the first case of second harmonic generation in the optical regime, a material response to high intensity light. However, important nonlinear effects had been discovered much earlier: the Kerr effect in 1874.

Polarization effects were known to prior to Newton's work on optics, based on [Iceland spar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceland_spar), in the mid-1600s, but these are explainable with linear optics. There is no intensity dependence.

But the research field of nonlinear optics begins the year after lasers: 1961.

Comment: Thanks. Thats the modern high energy nonlinear effect. The nonlinear crystals should have been known in 1700s.

Comment: See the additional reference to iceland spar. I work with non-linear crystals everyday, and do non-linear optics.  Perhaps you can update your question to be more specific.